# Is it silly to ask a writer to finish my script, but follow my key points

Tags: screenwriting, videogame

I'm working on a story for a video game I made that's supposed to be made into anime/visual novel, but  In the game you kill monsters so there's not much room for character development.

I have key point description of character goals and motivations, events where those change and different outcomes, since players influence the end of the story.

Is it silly to hire a writer to properly reveal character personalities through dialogs, monologs and non-monster-killing related events, but insist they hit milestones already established in the game ?

**EDIT**:
I'm not a writer at all, although I made up the universe of the story. I am well read so I know I can't do it as a side gig. It's a small commercial project that I finance myself and I really need the characters to be sympathetic and players to identify with them. The least I need are a bunch of scenes where characters think out loud and display their personalities, but that (to me) looks like a job nobody would take. I mean, what writer takes writing job where he can't decide what happens ?

Answer (score 2):

...I guess not? I mean, it depends.

You don't exactly say your a writer or not, and it doesn't sound like you're a fan of the idea of writing it yourself, so I'll assume writing it yourself is something you are trying to not do.

I'm also going to go ahead and point out this will probably be a Choose-Your-Own-Adventure-esque book based on what what you said. Some writers might not want to do that, so maybe pick a path or ending and have at least that one be written so you at least have something.

If you are not a writer yourself, or don't want to/don't have the time, then yes, it makes sense to outsource the writing. But you say it's supposed to be a visual story as well, which makes it a tad more complicated.

If you are going straight for visual, try to get one person to do both text and art so details aren't lost between them, or do the text yourself if you can so there's very minimal information loss.

Ultimately, with the information in the question, it's a matter of preference and convenience.

**Edit in response to edit:**

'The least I need are a bunch of scenes where characters think out loud and display their personalities but that (to me) looks like a job nobody would take. I mean, what writer takes writing job where he can't decide what happens?'

Plenty of writers. I'm sure there's a few on Fiver who would do it. That's also pretty much exactly what commissioned writers do, is write what you want. I'm not entirely sure what criteria exactly you would want for it, but you can probably find somebody on the internet who will do it.

Comment: I appreciate your input. I made an edit to better describe the situation.